# Adding defer attribute in .js files included in moodle

Tags: moodle

I am optimizing the performance of my Moodle site, it is showing the high loading time on loading the .js files of the page. That is why I want to include the `defer='defer'` attribute in the page which is calling or including the javascript files as follow.

```
if (!empty($CFG->cachejs) and !empty($CFG->jsrev) and $CFG->jsrev > 0 and substr($url, -3) === '.js') {
    if (empty($CFG->slasharguments)) {
        return new moodle_url($CFG->httpswwwroot.'/lib/javascript.php', array('rev'=>$CFG->jsrev, 'jsfile'=>$url));
    } else {
        $returnurl = new moodle_url($CFG->httpswwwroot.'/lib/javascript.php');
        $returnurl->set_slashargument('/'.$CFG->jsrev.$url);
        return $returnurl;
    }
} else {
    return new moodle_url($CFG->httpswwwroot.$url);
}
```

So how can I add the `defer='defer'` attribute on this? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple locations where javascript is embedded in the Moodle page, the biggest one is for the YUI3 library.

To add the defer tag, look in file `/lib/outputrequirementslib.php`. The exact line number depends on your Moodle version. The trickiest one is to add it to the `static.js` as this is handled in the html_writer class.

Please note that the tag should be "`defer`" and not "`defer='defer'`" as Moodle uses the HTML5 doctype.

Also the loading order for Moodle is important due to the way they have build it. Adding the defer attribute will probably break your Moodle.